# Writing data to firebase but instead the app stops

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write data to firebase but when `savetoFirebase` function is called the app stops.
**I think that there is some error in savetoFirebase function or the Firebase is not integrated properly**.
Here is function code.

```
private void saveToFirebase() {
        Location location = new Location("dummyprovider");
        LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Location mCurrentLocation = location;
        Map mLocations = new HashMap();
        Map  mCoordinate = new HashMap();
        mCoordinate.put("Latitude", mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        mCoordinate.put("Longitude", mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        mLocations.put("location", mCoordinate);
        String url = "MY-FIREBASE-APP";
        DatabaseReference myFirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
        myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(mLocations);

    }
```

I am calling this function when the y axis of accelerometer changes, also a beep plays when this value changes.
**A beep is still being played but after that app stops and a pop-up is displayed that the app has stopped.**

Here is full code of the app:

```
package com.example.hamzah.potholetrackingandmapping;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AccActivity, SensorEventListener {
    final static int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    final static String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    public GoogleMap mMap;
    public MarkerOptions mo;
    public Marker marker;
    public LocationManager locationManager;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private Sensor mAcc;
    private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ;
    private boolean mInitialized;
    private MediaPlayer player;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        // Get the default sensor of specified type
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mo = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("My Current Location");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !isPermissionGranted()) {
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        } else requestLocation();
        if (!isLocationEnabled())
            showAlert(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        marker = mMap.addMarker(mo);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        marker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
        int zoom = 15;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoordinates, zoom));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    private void requestLocation() {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 100, 10, this);
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    private boolean isPermissionGranted(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("myLog", "Permission is Granted");
                return true;
            }else {
                Log.v("myLog", "Permission not Granted");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void showAlert(final int status) {
        String message, title, btnText;
        if (status == 1) {
            message = "Your Location Setting is set to 'Off'\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                    "use this app";
            title = "Enable Location";
            btnText = "Location Settings";
        } else {
            message = "Please Allow this app to access location!";
            title =  "Permission Access";
            btnText = "Grant";
        }
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(btnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        if (status == 1) {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                        } else
                            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        if (!mInitialized) {
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            mInitialized = true;
        } else {

            float deltaY = y - mLastY;
            float deltaZ = z - mLastZ;

            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;

            if (deltaY < -3) {

                player.start();
                Location location = new Location("dummyprovider");
                LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                marker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
                saveToFirebase();
            }

        }
    }
    private void saveToFirebase() {
        Location location = new Location("dummyprovider");
        LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Location mCurrentLocation = location;
        Map mLocations = new HashMap();
        Map  mCoordinate = new HashMap();
        mCoordinate.put("Latitude", mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        mCoordinate.put("Longitude", mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        mLocations.put("location", mCoordinate);
        String url = "MY-FIREBASE-APP";
        DatabaseReference myFirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
        myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(mLocations);

    }



}
```

I have included the dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6`
The app stops and the data is not even written to the firebase.

Comment: If your app crashes there'll be an error message and stack trace in the logcat output. Find both and add them to your question to improve the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Have you configured your app correctly to communicate with Firestore, including the google-services.json file ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I testing this app on physical device since it is using accelerometer. It is just displaying app has stopped.

Comment: @113408 I hope I have configured my app correctly and it is communicating with firebase, included the .json file.

Comment: You can connect the `adb` tool to your physical device. See https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/ or some of these results: https://www.google.com/search?q=find+logcat+when+running+an+app+on+a+physical+device